# If-Else Statement Returning Same Feedback

Tags: c++, g++, clion

So for some reason no matter what I enter into this If-Else statement it returns with a "Program Aborted" as if I entered the wrong requested answers...very confused and I can't seem to find anything relevant enough around the site!

```
int ch;
cout << "Do you have any extra credit points? (Enter Y/y or N/n)" << endl;
cin >> ch;
int ExtraCredit;
if (ch == 'Y' || ch== 'y')
{
    cout << "Enter the number of extra credit points: ";
    cin >> ExtraCredit
}
else if (ch!='n' || ch!='N' || ch != 'y' || ch != 'Y')
{
    ExtraCredit=0; 
    cout<< Invalid entry. Program Aborted." << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Fix your formatting! My immediate thought was "How does this compile? There's a stray `else` hanging around!"

Comment: `ch` is an `int`. You are comparing it with characters. `cin` will fail to read `'Y'` as an integer.

Comment: Please edit your question to contain [mcve]

Comment: Post your real, compilable code.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux - OP never compares `ch` to a string. They only compare it to character constants, which get promoted to `ints` in this case.

Comment: `cin >> ch` wold not give you characters, as `ch` has type `int`. This is C++ not C

Comment: reconsider `ch!='n' || ch!='N' || ch != 'y' || ch != 'Y'`. If `ch` is 'n', then it isn't 'N`

Comment: Shouldn't the second if statement comparisons be separated `&&` rather than `||`?

Comment: Unsolicited advice: I'd change that `else if` to check for `'N'` and `'n'` and do nothing, then use an `else` for the fail case. That makes the logic clearer. Also, initializing `ExtraCredit` to 0 saves assigning 0 to it.

Comment: I commend converting to the answer to lower case (std::tolower) or to upper case (std::toupper) before comparing.  This reduces the number of comparisons (and typing) by 50%!

Comment: There's no reason for checking for 'Y' in the 2nd `if`.  You'll only get to the 2nd `if` when `ch` is not 'Y', so `ch` can't ever be 'Y' at the 2nd `if`.

Comment: Also, is there a need to check for `'n'` or `'N'`?  Think about it.  Credit is only give if the answer is `"Y/y"`.  For all other (*else*) conditions, there is no extra credit given.

Answer (score 5):

The issue appears very early:

```
int ch; // are you sure this should be an int?
cout << "Do you have any extra credit points? (Enter Y/y or N/n)" << endl;
cin >> ch;
```

`cin` behaves differently on `int` typed variables than on `char`s. When you enter "y" or "n" at the keyboard, `cin` will fail.

You can check whether `cin` failed by calling its `fail()` method, like so:

```
int num;
std::cout << "Enter a number: ";
std::cin >> num;
if (std::cin.fail()) {
    std::cout << ":(" << std::endl;
} else {
    std::cout << "Your number was " << num << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

ints and chars are separate types, even though they can be compared based on the ASCII value of the char in C++. Because they are defined as separate types, when your code gets to the line `cin >> ch` and `ch` is of type int, it waits for something to be entered. The prompt tells the user to enter a char, and they do. The code sees the char, and as it wasn't an int, nothing is read in and the value of `ch` is correctly determined by your code to be not y, Y, n, or N. If you'd like to `cin` a char, declare `char ch;`. If you'd like to have an int, prompt the user to enter a number.

Comment: Slight detail, its not guaranteed to be ASCII that's implementation/platform dependent.

Comment: The value is `ch` is not set at all when `cin` fails. It's value is uninitialized. Comparing it's value is undefined behavior, so saying that it isn't `Y`, `y`, `N` or `n` is meaningless.